# How do I return my own futures in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, future

In Java 8, I'm writing a DAO method which calls a method that returns a ListenableFuture (in this case it's a Cassandra async query that returns a ResultSetFuture).

However, I'm stuck on how I'm supposed to return a Future to the caller of the DAO method. I can't just return the ResultSetFuture because that future returns a ResultSet. I want to process the ResultSet and return a different object. For example:

```
public ListenableFuture<ThingObj> queryForThingAsync(String thingId) {
    ListenableFuture<ResultSet> rsFuture = db.getSession().executeAsync(QueryBuilder.select().all().from("thingSchema","Thing").where(eq("thingId",thingId)));
    // Now what? How do I create a ListenableFuture<ThingObj> given a ListenableFuture<ResultSet> and a method that can convert a ResultSet into a ThingObj?
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Java 8 concurrency types, or Guava? Guava has a `ListenableFuture` type, the JDK does not.

Comment: The Cassandra api returns a ListenableFuture, however I'd be happy to use the Java 8 concurrency types. I didn't actually notice that ListenableFuture was from guava. I now realize that CompletableFuture is probably the appropriate class to use. Even so, I'm still not sure how to do it.

Comment: OK - I'll update my answer to include an alternate solution using `CompletableFuture` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it appears you're using Guava's `ListenableFuture`, the easiest solution is the [transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) method from `Futures`:

> Returns a new ListenableFuture whose result is the product of applying the given Function to the result of the given Future.

There are a few ways to use it, but since you're on Java 8, the simplest is likely with a method reference:

```
public ListenableFuture<ThingObj> queryForThingAsync(String thingId) {
    ListenableFuture<ResultSet> rsFuture = db.getSession().executeAsync(QueryBuilder.select().all().from("thingSchema","Thing").where(eq("thingId",thingId)));
    return Futures.transform(rsFuture, Utils::convertToThingObj);
}
```

Comment: I found a converter java8-guava (https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter/blob/master/README.md) which converts between the two types. I just use FutureConverter.toCompletableFuture to convert from ListenableFuture to CompletableFuture. Then I call thenApply on the CompletableFuture. That appears to do the same thing as Futures.transform. Thanks!